# Jersey: ContainerRequestFilter throwing Error

Tags: java, rest, jersey, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard with jersey, 
I defined a custom provider of ContainerRequestFilter by the following method

```
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Provider
public class CustomRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter{

  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRequestFilter.class);

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {


    MultivaluedMap<String,String> myHeaders = requestContext.getHeaders();
    List<String> appId = myHeaders.get("myHeader");
    logger.info(myHeader.get(0));
    logger.info("Hello Word, it is customRequestFilter");


  }

}
```

but the System is throwing an error

```
ERROR [2014-05-26 10:04:46,556] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.filter.FilterFactory: The filter, of type myPackage.CustomRequestFilter, MUST be of the type String, String[], Class<? extends 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter>, or an instance of 
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter. The filter is ignored.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is just a question of using the right imports. Try this:

```java
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilter;

@Provider
public class CustomRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomRequestFilter.class);

  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest requestContext) {
    MultivaluedMap<String,String> myHeaders = requestContext.getRequestHeaders();
    List<String> appId = myHeaders.get("myHeader");
    logger.info(appId.get(0));
    logger.info("Hello Word, it is customRequestFilter");
    return requestContext;
  }

}
```

Comment: shouldn't sun.* classes be avoided for developing puropose. And I believe there are package available here https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/package-summary.html